# Issue with multiple elements in a change function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox, onchange

I have two sections that will be displayed in my fiddle. The first section you chose a product (A or B). Then whenever you choose an option a next button is displayed. When you click next it takes you to the second section which shows the product selection.

I believe my issue resides within my change functions or if statements within it. Basically, I am unsure of what I am doing wrong with the code that starts with this:

```
  $('#package1, #package2').on('change', function () {
        if ($('#package1' && '#package2').prop("checked")) {
```

I am wanting to format the second section (after the products were selected) different based on the selection. What I am struggling to do is if product A and B are both selected to only show the product A section `#pg-review-section` in the second section and hide the product B section `#tp-selection`.

Essentially, I am unsure of how to modify the code if both A and B are selected, but I want it to run off of a change function in case the selections change at any point.

[Here is a fiddle for demonstration.](https://jsfiddle.net/qshmxnuw/)

The code below is what I am struggling with.

```
$('#package1', '#package2').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#package1' && '#package2').prop("checked")) {
        $('#pg-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-selection').hide();
        $('#tp-selection').fadeBoolToggle($('#calendar-preview-select option:selected'));
    }
});
$('#package1').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#package1').prop("checked")) {
        $('#pg-selection').show();
        $('#pg-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-review-section').hide();
    } else {
        $('#pg-selection').hide();
    }
});
$('#package2').on('change', function () {
    if ($('#package2').prop("checked")) {
        $('#tp-selection').show();
        $('#tpreview-section').show();
        $('#pg-review-section').hide();
    } else {
        $('#tp-selection').hide();
    }
});
```

UPDATED:

```
$('#package1, #package2').on('change', function () {
     if ($('#package1').prop('checked') && $('#package2').prop('checked').length === 2) {
        $('#pg-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-selection').hide();
        $('#tp-selection').fadeBoolToggle($('#calendar-preview-select option:selected'));
    }
     else if ($('#package1').prop("checked") && !$('#package2').prop('checked')) {
        $('#pg-selection').show();
        $('#pg-review-section').show();
        $('#tp-review-section').hide();
    }
     else if ($('#package2').prop("checked") && !$('#package1').prop('checked')) {
        $('#tp-selection').show();
        $('#tp-review-section').show();
        $('#pg-review-section').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think `$('#package1', '#package2')` should be `$('#package1, #package2')` - note the quotes. Also, you need to discover the `checked` state separately, ie `if ($('#package1').prop('checked') && $(''#package2').prop('checked'))`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong because changing to your solution is still shows product B.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan In my question I added updated code of what I am trying now. This does not work. I changed the structure some.

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Basically if you click on Product A and B (the icon where the img would be). Then proceed. I just want A's content to show (right now B is showing as well). Then when you select one of A's options (1, 2, or 3) it will show B. I expanded on my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qshmxnuw/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery selector `:checked` and test the length:

```
if ($('#package1:checked, #package2:checked').length === 2)
```

https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: Not sure what I am doing wrong, but this doesn't seem to help. It still shows product B.

Comment: In my question I added updated code of what I am trying now. This does not work. I changed the structure some.

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Basically if you click on Product A and B (the icon where the img would be). Then proceed. I just want A's content to show (right now B is showing as well). Then when you select one of A's options (1, 2, or 3) it will show B. I expanded on my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qshmxnuw/1/

Answer (score 0):

In your updated version you are missing ".length" on package1 in your first if statement.

If the logic you want is:

a checked => go to a section

b checked => go to b section

both checked => go to a section

Why not just create a generic function to add to your change events? something similar to this?

```
$('#package1').on('change', function () {
    myChangeFunction();
});
$('#package2').on('change', function () {
    myChangeFunction();
});
function myChangeFunction(){
   if ($('#package2').prop("checked") && $('#package1').prop("checked")){
      // show a and hide b
   }
   else if($('#package1').prop("checked")){
      // show a and hide b
   }
   else if($('#package2').prop("checked")){
      //  show b and hide a
   }
   else{
      //hide both
   }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Basically if you click on Product A and B (the icon where the img would be). Then proceed. I just want A's content to show (right now B is showing as well). Then when you select one of A's options (1, 2, or 3) it will show B. I expanded on my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/qshmxnuw/1/

Comment: Just to clarify when you select A on the first screen you want A options to show (1, 2, 3). Then if any of the options are selected show B? And what about option B on the first page?

Comment: Yes, I want product B to show if (1, 2 or 3) is selected ONLY if Product A and B are both selected from the first section.

Comment: You're missing a few ending div tags in your fiddle, I assume that's not the case your code. To get the functionality you want, change the fadeBoolToggle to hide() instead. This will hide B when you open A. Then hook into the change event of the options 1,2,3 checkboxes that will then show option B. Let me know if that doesn't make sense and I'll update my answer above.